# jquery cookie append values through loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am currently trying to loop through an array and append id's to my current jquery cookie but cant see to get it working the way I'd like to.

```
$.cookie('sampleCookie', 'true');
$.cookie.json = true;
var arrayTest=[{id: 'id1', key: 'true'},{id: 'id2', key: 'true'},{id: 'id3', key: 'true'}];

                    for (var i = arrayTest.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                        var currentId = arrayTest[i].id;
                        $.cookie('sampleCookie' + '&' + currentId);             
                    }
```

This code block doesnt seem to produce the output I am looking for.

I'd like the cookie to look like "true&id1&id2&id3"

Comment: It's usually `$.cookie(name, value)`, it seems you're trying to store the value in a very complicated name instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Adeneo,

this worked for me.

```
$.cookie('sampleCookie', $.cookie('sampleCookie') + '&' + currentId);
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried your code which is perfect for me but I am getting first undefined value in my cookie. Any Idea about this. This is my result: `undefined, Chrysanthemum.jpg, Desert.jpg`. I have also check by alerting but I am not getting undefined anything.

Comment: This is my jQuery cookie code: `jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added') + ', ' + a.name);`